# Dynamically create XmlListModel?

Tags: application-development, ubuntu-touch

Is it possible to dynamically create XmlListModel using a javascript function in a .qml file?

Also, what can I execute qml file with so that I can get console.log() to the command line?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can do this - you would lack a reference in the main .qml to the XmlListModel

Simply use qmlscene from the console while in your project directory to see the output